# finding MAX for relational algebra

Tags: sql, max, relational-database, relational-algebra

Given the folllowing sql query where I can find the name of the most expensive pizza

```
SELECT p.name
FROM PIZZA p
WHERE p.price=(
                SELECT MAX(p.price)
                FROM PIZZA p
               );
```

How would I make this into relational algebra? Should this be fine

```
PROJECT p1.code - PROJECT p2.code(
                                  SELECT p1.price >= p2.price
                                  (P(p1,p) X P(p2,p)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
σ rownum() > 0 and rownum() ≤ 1 τ price desc π price Serves
```